# How to use pandas to count the value from multiple column at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook

I learned that when I type `df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")`, I can bring this data from csv file like below :

```
    round        date  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth  bonus
0      959  2021.04.17      1      14     15      24     40     41     35
1      958  2021.04.10      2       9     10      16     35     37      1
2      957  2021.04.03      4      15     24      35     36     40      1
3      956  2021.03.27     10      11     20      21     25     41     40
4      955  2021.03.20      4       9     23      26     29     33      8
```

Also I learned that I can use `df["column_name"].value_counts()` to count how frequently the value wrote.

For example, `df["first"].value_count()`, then it will show the 'first' column's count value as a result. like

```
1     134
2     107
3      94 ...
```

But I want to count the all the value in multiple column at once.

How can I count the value from multiple column at once? Can some tell me which method to use?

Comment: Can you add expected output? e.g. for first 5 columns?

Comment: If I take the table above as an example,                                                                              
1    3 ;
2    1 ;
4     2 ;
...

41  2  ;      Kind like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can select all columns without first 2, use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with your solution:

```
s = df.iloc[:, 2:].melt()['value'].value_counts().sort_index()
print (s)
1     3
2     1
4     2
8     1
9     2
10    2
11    1
14    1
15    2
16    1
20    1
21    1
23    1
24    2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a matrix of all present values in all columns from `start` to end, use `value_counts` as suggested by @jezrael and sum them through columns axis:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int).sum(axis=1)
1     3
2     1
4     2
8     1
9     2
10    2
11    1
14    1
15    2
16    1
20    1
21    1
23    1
24    2
25    1
26    1
29    1
33    1
35    3
36    1
37    1
40    3
41    2
dtype: int64
```